# Condition based grouping

Tags: mysql

My database table list is

```
product_no | c_product_no| qty  | price
1001       | 4306-0      | 15   | 100
1001       | 4306-0      | 15   | 100
665        | 5906-7      | 981  | 2547
783        | 5906-7      | 1221 | 200
783        | 590111      | 5    | 300
783        | 5906-7      | 1221 | 200
```

And I am expecting output is

```
product_no | c_product_no| qty  | price
1001       | 4306-0      | 30   | 100
665        | 5906-7      | 981  | 2547
783        | 5906-7      | 2442 | 200
783        | 590111      | 5    | 300
```

My condition in grouping is product_no and c_product_no and price same grouped the data and sum of quenty

Comment: Are these tables in your database or are these columns in your table?
Please rephrase the question, it will help us answer it better. :-)

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which will likely prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_no, c_product_no, SUM(qty), price 
FROM table 
GROUP BY product_no, c_product_no, price
```

This answer assumes that price is same for all records that have same (product_no, c_product_no). We group by data product_no, c_product_no and price (actually this is not necessary. We are including price in group by so that we can include it in the select part).

SUM (qty) will compute the sum of quantity of all records with same product_no, c_product_no, price combination

Comment: While this may answer the question, please add a short explanation what your code actually does and how it solves the initial problem. Don't just drop some lines of code.

Comment: my question is group with some condition . product_no , c_product_no, | price above column values are same then it's grou